# jQuery hover over text to display an image with fade

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, navigation, hover

I am having trouble with my navigation at the moment, I am trying to have an inline list display an image similar to an underline with a fade in and out.

currently I have the whole li fading in and out, text included. I only want the image to fade in and out under the text.

I am not the best at jQuery, it is a bit of a combination of tutorials at the moment.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">what we do</a></li>
        <li><a href="">our work</a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul li{
margin: 0 0 0 22px;
padding: 0 0 20px;
display: inline;
background: url(../img/3bullets.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
nav ul li a{
color: #fff;
font-family: Heiti TC, Tahoma, Verdana;
font-size: 21px;
letter-spacing: -0.5px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(navigationhover){
    $("nav ul li").fadeTo("slow", 0.1); // Sets the opacity to fade down when the page loads
    $("nav ul li").hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // Sets the opacity on hover
    },function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.1); // Sets the opacity on mouseout
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated as this has had me stuck for awhile!

Thanks.

Comment: it works in FF but not in IE. Look at this example, guess you need an extra conditional for IE http://jquery.malsup.com/fadetest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the anchor tag is a child of the LI it will fade out with it's parent, have you considered adding an hr element to the li?

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="">home</a><hr></li>
        <li><a href="">what we do</a><hr></li>
        <li><a href="">our work</a><hr></li>
        <li><a href="">contact us</a><hr></li>
        <li><a href="">blog</a><hr></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul li h2{
background: url(../img/3bullets.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(navigationhover){
    $("nav ul li h2").fadeTo("slow", 0.1); // Sets the opacity to fade down when the page loads
    $("nav ul li").hover(function(){
        $('h2', this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // Sets the opacity on hover
    },function(){
        $('h2', this).fadeTo("slow", 0.1); // Sets the opacity on mouseout
    });
});
```

EDIT: it works, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f6N9F/)

Comment: cheers trey, although this didn't work perfectly first time is helped me solve the problem! thank you. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uus9h/) which if copied and an image added to the hr background, works.

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand your question correctly, you want to fade the background you're setting in your css?

Comment: Hi, yes.. I understand I may need to change the structure a bit but I am not sure the best way to go about it.